# Put request doesn't get to my controller by feign client, getting 415 status code

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

this is my feign client code

```
@RequestLine("PUT /merchants/{merchantId}")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
MerchantDTO updateMerchant(@Param("merchantId") Long merchantId, PutMerchantDTO putMerchantDTO);
```

which is called in some requestFactory class.
And this one is my controller code

```
@PutMapping(value = "/merchants/{merchantId}")
ResponseEntity<MerchantDTO> updateMerchant(@RequestBody @NotEmpty PutMerchantDTO updateMerchantRequest, @PathVariable("merchantId") final Long merchantId) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(merchantUpdateMapper.toDtoMerchant(merchantUpdateService.processUpdate(merchantUpdateMapper.toDomain(updateMerchantRequest, merchantId))));
}
```

Can somebody Please tell me why I'm getting 415 when doing the put request with this feign Client to my controller?

Comment: Have you tried enabling Feign logging to see the actual request being sent out?

Answer (score 0):

remove `@Headers`
and in `@PutMapping` add `consumes = "application/json"`

Comment: unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

@PutMapping(value = "/merchants/{merchantId}") you write the same line like you specified in feign client

and change @Param("merchantId") to @PathVariable("merchantId")

Comment: I did what you said, but again no result